# Rotation Number of Polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

I conjectured that Maximum Rotation Number of $n$-th degree polynomial image of unit circle

(in the complex plane)  is $n$.

(for example, if $f(z)=z^n$, then rotation number is $n$)

Is it right?

Comment: What is the "rotation number of a polynomial"?

Comment: Do you mean the winding number?

Comment: If you mean winding number then it depends around which point. See http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+-%28cos%282+t%29%2Bsin%28t%29%29%2Ccos%28t%29+%28-1%2B2+sin%28t%29%29 where $p(x)=x^2-x$ and take the point +0.5 or the point -0.5 giving a different result.

Comment: It differs from winding number; for example, in the figure '8', the rotation number is zero but winding number in any interior point is one...

Comment: Rotation number means the total variations of tangent lines of the curve. However, winding number depends on both curves and the criteria point.